# peer automatically stopped listening, but container didn't exit and didn't throw any error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Peer automatically stopped listening, but the container didn't exit and didn't throw any error. When I am trying to invoke, it is happening. I'm using Hyperledger Fabric 2.0

**Error:**

```
[EventService]: unregisterEventListener[peer0.org1.example.com:8051] - #104 - event listener was not found
```

Comment: From what I can understand from the error, unregisterEventListener method expects its first argument to be an eventListener, which I think you didn't provide and that's why you're getting the error. Refer this https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/master/EventService.html#unregisterEventListener

Comment: But this problem came in between of processing.... I am try to invoke and query more then 20000 data.

Comment: Query & Invoke are two different kinds of operations in Hyperledger Fabric. Are you using both?

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say "Peer automatically stopped listening"? What logs do you see on peer container? Run "docker logs PEER_DOCKER_CONTAINER --tail 200" to get the last 200 logs.

Comment: goroutine 368 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.(*kvLedger).CommitLegacy(0xc0002a5b90, 0xc007282de0, 0xc0086214a4, 0x0, 0x0)
 /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/kv_ledger.go:468 +0xe30

Comment: yes, first I am going to query the hyper ledger data to check the data is there or not. if data is not there I will insert. this process will happen up to 2 lack data